# The value of template type like std::false_type

Tags: c++, templates

If `std::false_type` is a type, what is the valid value for this type?
If I just want to implement a function like below whose return type is `std::false_type`, how could I achieve this?

```
typename std::false_type operator()(){
   return declval<std::false_type>();
}
```

Comment: `return std::false_type{}`?

Comment: Or just `return {};`.

Comment: `std::false_type` is intended to support template meta-programming. As such, it’s used at **compile** time to select template instantiations. At runtime, use `bool`, `true`, and `false`.

Comment: I intend to implement tag dispatching at compile time like func(true_type) and func(false_type) and that's why I cannot declare its type is just simple boolean.

Comment: Such types might be "implemented" as empty `struct`. This is because not the contents is the intention but the type name itself (which can become subject of type evaluation). Hence, the value might be `void`. I remember that void `struct`s are prevented by C++ compilers. Instead they get some dummy contents for internal technical reasons (e.g. 4 bytes with no meaning except alignment). As long as you do (compile time) type evaluation (but not instancing) of these types this has no run-time effect at all.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I got your intention. However, once I found a nice solution in gtkmm to distinguish constructors (with otherwise identical signature). The gtkmm authors defined an `enum` for each of these constructors. Each of these `enum`s contained only one enumerator. You had to call the constructor with the resp. enumerator ID. The constructor implementation didn't read the enumerator at all but the compiler can use the `enum` type to distinguish which constructor to use. (Of course, this works for non-constructor functions as well.) I'm not sure whether this causes any run-time...

Comment: ...effort at all or is "optimized away" completely. (I didn't expect much effort and didn't care about this.) A look into the assembly code (e.g. on godbolt) might answer this.

Answer (score 3):

The only value that `std::false_type` can have is the default constructed one. It is a class type with no non-static data members, and no user defined constructor.

```
std::false_type operator()(){
    return {};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `return std::false_type{};` or `return {};` as suggested in the comment.